# How do I do a Py3k pickle dump?

Tags: python, python-3.x, marshalling, pickle, utf

I'm getting the following error via cgitb:

```
TypeError: must be str, not bytes 
      args = ('must be str, not bytes',) 
      with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of TypeError object>
```

The line of code that is singled out is:

```
pickle.dump(state, output_file)
```

The output file is opened to a particular path for writing.

I don't think I've seen "hello pickle" for Py3k's creating, marshalling, and unmarshalling a "hello world" string the new way. Anyone be willing to explain what I need to be doing differently with the file (specify UTF-8 encoding or something), and post "Hello world" that marshals and unmarshals from Py3k's basic string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are opening the file in `w` or `r` mode, change it to `wb`, It should work. Basically, open it in binary mode.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was missing.